# What does Super-O do on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I am running Linux Mint, with Cinnamon 19. I accidentally pressed <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, and the following popup icon appeared:

[image]

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> again seems to 'toggle' the setting, now showing this:

[image]

I looked through all of the keyboard shortcuts listed in the keyboard preferences, but <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> wasn't listed.

I want to find out what exactly <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> does, and what is the default option, so I can put it back how it was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screen rotation on/off. Some laptops support it much like tablets and phones.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> System -> Hardware -> Orientation Lock. The default option is "Super-O". You can reset it to "unassigned" or assign it with a new key.

Comment: “mumble mumble mumble **Orientation Lock**” doesn’t answer the question: ***what** does it **do**?* If you mean this to be a supplement to the other answer; don’t do that.  Each answer should answer the question all by itself. (You may *refer* to other answer(s).)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was answering the "what is the default option, so I can put it back how it was?" part.

Comment: OK; so what is the default option?  I don’t see where you answered that.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is updated.

Comment: But you’re answering the wrong question. The question isn’t “What is the default keyboard shortcut for Orientation Lock?”; it is “What is the default ***state*** for Orientation Lock: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyXzH.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YWSO.png)?”